# Javascript Infinite Loop does not loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Javascript that loops infinitly.

```
function scroll(num) {
    $("." + num + "").fadeOut('slow');
    var choose = num + 1;
    $("." + choose + "").fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function() {
        scroll(choose);
    }, 1000);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    scroll('1');
}, 1000);​
```

It does the function the first time but does not continue.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using one as both a string and as an integer: Calling `scroll('1')` means that `num + 1` will return `"11"`, not `2` as you expect. Try this instead:

```
function scroll(num) {
    $("." + num.toString()).fadeOut('slow');
    var choose = num + 1;
    $("." + choose.toString()).fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function() {
        scroll(choose);
    }, 1000);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    scroll(1);
}, 1000);​
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding 1 to the  string "1" resulting in "11". is this what you meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here Problem is with your Concatenating,using + to Concatenating is ambiguous in your code . 
In your code var choose = num + 1; will return 11 as string not 2 as per your expectation.